# tr display none crashes ie9

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

This code crashes ie9 as i am having this problem in my code .. any work around will be appreciated .. This is not a problem with the previous versions of ie .. Thanks ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse">
            <tr id="firsttr">
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="secondtr">
                <td></td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #D2D2D2">Move cursor here</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <style type="text/css">
        #secondtr:hover {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
</html>
```

Even using onclick event crashes the browser .. try the following ..
                
                    
                    Move cursor here

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function HideThis()
    {
        document.getElementById('secondtr').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Confirmed to be reproducible.

Comment: Your code tries to remove from display the object on which the mouse is hovering. Is that desired ?

Comment: Seems to be related to: `First-chance exception at 0x7645b9bc (KernelBase.dll) in iexplore.exe: 0x800706BA: The RPC server is unavailable.`

Comment: @dystroy Yeah i need this to work .. as this is a simple javascript functionality which works perfectly with other browsers ..

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem, and have found a solution.
First of all I should say that the problem is actual for any row in table with style borderCollapse equal to collapse (no matter if it is declared inline or in head) in IE9.

My solution:

```
function hideRow(tableNode, rowNode, hide){
    if(hide){
        if(window.navigator.userAgent.search('MSIE 9.0') != -1){
            var initValue = tableNode.style.borderCollapse;
            tableNode.style.borderCollapse = 'separate';
            rowNode.style.display = 'none';
            tableNode.style.borderCollapse = initValue;
        }else{
            rowNode.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }else{
        rowNode.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Or even shorten:

```
function hideRow(tableNode, rowNode, hide){
    var initValue = tableNode.style.borderCollapse;
    tableNode.style.borderCollapse = 'separate';
    rowNode.style.display = hide ? 'none' : '';
    tableNode.style.borderCollapse = initValue;
}
```

Comment: +1 For you. Replace `tableNode.style.borderCollapse` by `tableNode.currentStyle.borderCollapse`,
try: `var initValue=tableNode.style.borderCollapse || tableNode.currentStyle.borderCollapse;` and then: `if(initValue){ tableNode.style.borderCollapse = initValue; }`

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in IE9, but the css rule is logically undecidable :

As soon as it isn't displayed any more, your mouse isn't hovering any more so it must be visible again. Which means the mouse is over it. Which means it must be hidden... which means it must be visible... etc.

Said otherwise : the specification doesn't make sense.

This being said, this bug is really annoying as the following code crashes IE9 too :

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('#secondtr').mouseenter(function(){
         $('#secondtr').hide();
    });
});
```

But it doesn't happen if you put your event handler on a `span` (for example). So I suggest you change your HTML in order to avoid hidding the `tr` on which you have a hovering detection.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in IE9.

Changing `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`, you will see the text flash continuously.

The only think I can think of is the IE gets stuck in an infinite loop or a stackoverflow.

Sorry, that I can't provide a solution.

Comment: The infinite loop is normal (see my answer).

Comment: @dystroy: yep, I saw (+1'd it)

Comment: @dystroy If this is an infinite loop .. then try this  <tr id="secondtr" onclick='HideThis()'> and inside the function hide the tr by setting display:none .. You will notice this is not an infinite loop ..<script type="text/javascript">
 function HideThis()
 {
  document.getElementById('secondtr').style.display = 'none';
 }
</script>

Comment: The above mentioned code works fine in other versions of ie and other browers .. that is the onclick function .. but not in ie9 ..

Answer (score 0):

If hiding the TR is what you want, you could try something like:

```
#secondtr:hover {
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

Here's the the complete code that worked for me on IE , FF and Safari:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<TITLE> BLAH</TITLE>
<style type="text/css">
#secondtr:hover, #secondtr:hover .secondTD  {
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.secondTD{
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr id="firsttr">
        <td colspan="2"> </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="secondtr">
        <td></td>
        <td  class="secondTD">Move cursor here</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```